# Using Accessor methods to access data from another class

Tags: java, class, methods, output, accessor

I am relatively new to java and learning to program, this being my 8th week at uni. I have been fiddling around with my code for the past day and I have been searching for the past hour or two for a similar question that could help answer my problem but have not found one that helps my particular situation, at least not that I could understand.

For an assignment, I have been asked to write a program with 3 classes(an interface, a store and a product class) and I have been going ok until I need to display data on the interface that is held in the product class. At the moment the code will compile fine but when I run the program and try to use the writeOutput() method I get a stack overflow error. Anyway this is what I have so far:

This is the method I am trying to get to work in the interface class:

```
private void writeOutput()
{
    int productChoice;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose a product (1),(2),(3)");
    productChoice = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The records of product " +productChoice+ " are:");
    System.out.println("Name: "+matesStore.getName());
```

And this is one of the methods from the store class:

```
public String getName()
{
        return getName();            
}
```

Finally I'll include the getter and setter from the product class just in case:

```
public void setName(String newName) 
{
    name = newName;
}    
public String getName()
{
    return name;        
}
```

Hopefully this is enough information for someone to be able to help me but if it is not, I am happy to upload all three classes in their entirety.

Cheers Cale.

Edit: I have decided to add all three classes to help people who wish to help me (just keep in mind that I am nowhere near finishing and my code is probably riddled with problems) Hopefully it's not too messy for you guys to understand. And sorry for not writing many comments, it's something i need to work on :)

```
import java.util.*;
public class MatesInterface
{
Store matesStore = new Store();

private void run()
{      
    showInterface();
    chooseOption();
}
private void showInterface()
{
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?:");
    System.out.println("(1)Input data for the product");
    System.out.println("(2)Show data from one product");
    System.out.println("(3)Show the replenishment strategy for a product");
    System.out.println("(0)Exit the program"); 
}
private void chooseOption()
{        
    int option;
    boolean flag = false;  

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);          
    System.out.print("Please choose an option: ");
    option = console.nextInt();

    if(option==1)
    {
        readInput();                            
    }
    else if(option==2)
    {
        writeOutput();
    }
    else if (option==3)
    {

    }
    else if(option==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        flag = true;
    }


    while (flag)
    {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid option.");
        System.out.println("Please choose an option: ");
        option = console.nextInt();
        flag = false;
    }   

}

private void readInput()
{
    Store matesStore = new Store();
    String name;
    int productChoice, demandRate;
    double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellingPrice;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose a product (1), (2) or (3): ");
    productChoice = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the product's name: ");
    name = console.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the product's demand rate: ");
    demandRate = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the product's setup cost: ");
    setupCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the product's unit cost: ");
    unitCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the product's inventory cost: ");
    inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the product's selling price: ");
    sellingPrice = console.nextDouble();
    matesStore.addData(productChoice, name, demandRate, setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellingPrice);
    chooseOption();
}
private void writeOutput()
{
    int productChoice;

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please choose a product (1),(2),(3)");
    productChoice = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The records of product " +productChoice+ " are:");
    System.out.println("Name: "+matesStore.getName());
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{        
    MatesInterface intFace = new MatesInterface();
    intFace.run();
}
}





public class Store
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private Product product1, product2, product3;

public Store()
{
    product1 = new Product();
    product2 = new Product();
    product3 = new Product();
}

public void addData(int option, String newName, int newDemand, double newSetup, double newUnit, double newInventory, double newPrice)
{
    if (option==1) setData(product1, newName, newDemand, newSetup, newUnit, newInventory, newPrice);
    else if (option==2) setData(product2, newName, newDemand, newSetup, newUnit, newInventory, newPrice);
    else setData(product3, newName, newDemand, newSetup, newUnit, newInventory, newPrice);
}
private void setData(Product product, String name, int demandRate, double setupCost, double unitCost, double inventoryCost, double sellingPrice)
{
    product.setName(name);
    product.setDemand(demandRate);
    product.setSetup(setupCost);
    product.setUnit(unitCost);
    product.setInventory(inventoryCost);
    product.setPrice(sellingPrice);        
}

public String getName()
{
        return getName();            
}
}




import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Product
{
private String name;
private int demandRate;
//private final int REPLENISHMENTRATE=0;
private double setupCost;
private double unitCost;
private double inventoryCost;
private double sellingPrice; 

//Constructors for the class Product
public Product()
{
    name = "No name yet.";
    demandRate = 0;
    unitCost = 0;
    setupCost = 0;
    inventoryCost = 0;
    sellingPrice = 0;        
}       
public Product(String newName, int newDemand, double newSetup, double newUnit, double newInventory, double newPrice)
{
    name = newName;
    demandRate = newDemand;
    unitCost = newUnit;
    setupCost = newSetup;
    inventoryCost = newInventory;
    sellingPrice = newPrice;
}

// Accessor and mutator methods to access and modify data on a Product object
public void setName(String newName) 
{
    name = newName;
}    
public String getName()
{
    return name;        
}

public void setDemand(int newDemand)
{
    demandRate = newDemand;
}    
public int getDemand()
{
   return demandRate;
}

public void setUnit(double newUnit)
{
   unitCost = newUnit;
}   
public double getUnit()
{
   return unitCost;
}

public void setSetup(double newSetup)
{
   setupCost = newSetup;
}    
public double getSetup()
{
   return setupCost;
}

public void setInventory(double newInventory)
{
   inventoryCost = newInventory;
}   
public double getInventory()
{
   return inventoryCost;
}

public void setPrice(double newPrice)
{
   sellingPrice = newPrice;
}   
public double getPrice()
{
   return sellingPrice;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method from the store class is recursivelly calling itself with no terminating clause, this is leading to StackOverflowError :

```
public String getName()
{
    return getName();    // calls itself        
}
```

Instead return the value of name variable if it exists in Store class, or whatever variable you want to be returned as a name:

```
public String getName()
{
    // determine the product name you want
    return myProduct.getName();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. However name does not exist in the Store class. Perhaps it would have been better if I uploaded all three classes.

Comment: when you call matesStore.getName() what do you expect to be returned

Comment: The value of name that is being stored in Product.

Comment: how do you determine which product you want ?

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest. I probably should've figured that out before asking this question..

Comment: yes..but as far as your question regarding stackoverflow is concerned, that was because of non-terminating recursive call

Comment: Perhaps I could just work out how to display the data for all 3 products now and come back to that later as I'm not entirely sure the user is meant to choose a product to display.

Comment: Ok thank you :) that's one problem solved, unfortunately it doesn't help me in figuring out how to properly display the data from the Product class in the MatesInterface class.